# Kinesis Firehose demo has no delimiters; Redshift can't parse without. Which is wrong?

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

When I went through first learning steps with Kinesis, Firehose, and Redshift today, I was pleased to discover that Amazon had a "try our demo data producer" setup.

I was frustrated to learn that it does not seem to actually work.

So, I went digging.  And I found `STL_LOAD_ERROR` contained errors suggesting that a delimiter was expected, and records' fronts that looked like `{field:val,field:val}{field:val,field:val}`.

```
...{"TICKER_SYMBOL": |     1214 | Delimiter not found
```

"Must be stripping newlines somewhere," I thought.

After digging, I found that there are production records in the relevant S3 bucket, in a surprising format:

```
{field:val,field:val}{field:val,field:val}...
```

That is, there are no delimiters between the apparent records, which are single line files of several dozen K each.

[Other SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38253346/763127) seem to suggest that this is actually the expected data format.

Why does Redshift need data in a format the data demo doesn't use?  Which do I reconfigure?

Comment: Two things learned so far.  1) Example data is in JSON.  JSON needs to be turned on as a COPY command.  JSON as 'auto'   2) Example data has upper case keys.  Redshift has lower case only, case sensitive column names.  Need JSONpaths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay.  There were three problems.

1. The AWS example data producer produces data in a format which needs alterations to the Redshift COPY command, but they don't tell you that.
2. You need to add FORMAT AS JSON 's3://yourbucketname/aJsonPathFile.txt'
3. You need to create a [JSON path file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#r_COPY_command_examples-load-listing-from-an-amazon-s3-bucket) because the default data producer produces upper-case column names, which redshift cannot consume

Answer (score 0):

I also just ran into this issue. The root of issue is as you pointed out, the data generated has column names which are all upper-case, while the table creation code snippet has all lower-case column names.

The easiest solution I found was to change COPY command suggested (in Step 2) from "json 'auto'", to include 'ignorecase':

```
json 'auto ignorecase'
```

This should solve the error with data generation without needing to create a custom JSON path file.

[You can see here for the documentation on this syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#copy-from-json-examples-using-auto-ignorecase).